# NTFS Partition on a USB Stick shows up as FAT32 and is unaccessible in Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, partitioning, ntfs, liveusb

Hi I have the following Problem:

I installed Tails on a 16GB USB Drive (Kingston DataTraveler SE9 G2) and then created an 8GB NTFS Partition (also tried FAT32) and then created an 4.6 GB encrypted Volume.

I wanted to be able to access the 8GB Partition from Windows Clients, but i cant access this Partition under Windows.

It works fine under Linux Mint DE2 and under the Tails OS (can create and read files with both OS's) but when I am in Windows it doesnt recognize the Partition - diskmgmt.msc even tells me it is a FAT32 Partition with the size of the Tails Partition

I have tried to reformat the Partition with GParted under Linux but I still have the same Problem. The Properties of the 8GB Partition shows actually the 2.6 GB Partition in which Tails is located and if I try to rightclick the first Partition I just get "Help" in the context menu.

Unfortunately I am all out of ideas how I could solve this Problem and maybe someone here can help me figure out how to fix that.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not generally like accessing partitions on USB devices that are not the first partition on the device. I have had success putting the commonly accessible partition first, followed by `/boot` followed by the root partition.

Comment: Ok, thx for the input my problem is the Tails Partition has to be the first one or I cant use the encrypted partition (at least not with big problems that I have to solve if i do) but thank you very much. But I'll give it a try on a second USB Stick.

Comment: Works, thx a lot ! ^^

Comment: FYI: You can workaround this known windows bug by changing the USB pendrive to a non removeable type. That requires changing its ID by reprogramming the chip on the pen drtive. Quite annoying given that it works on every OS except on windows.